# Composition between mixed functions (scalar, vector...)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider

$$f(x, y) = x^2+y^2 \qquad \qquad g(t) = (2t, t^2)$$

So $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$.

I know that then $g\circ f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

If instead I want $f\circ g$, in this case I can do it because it's like to write $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, so then

$$f\circ g: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$$

But in the end, I don't really know how to compose. I don't get it at all.

perpahs is it

$$f\circ g = f(g(t)) = (2t)^2 + (t^2)^2$$

??

And is it

$$g\circ f = g(f(x,y)) = 2t^2 + t^4$$

??
Help me thank you!

Comment: It is $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\circ g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (you wrote it the other way around). About computing the composition take a look at the answer by obscurans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$.
> I know that then $g\circ f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

False. If $f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$, then $g\circ f: A\to C$. In your case, that means $g\circ f: \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, which you can also see if you just write it out:

$$g(f(x, y))=(2f(x,y), (f(x,y))^2) = (2x^2+2y^2, x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4)$$

Comment: Thank you so much, it's better now. Just the last trouble: say I have $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Then if I understood well, I cannot do $f\circ g$ but I can do $g\circ f$, right?

Comment: @Numb3rs No. You are wrong again. Please re-read my answer. If $f: A\to B$, and $g: B\to C$, then you can calculate $g\circ f$.

Comment: Lol sorry, I inverted the "can" - "cannot". The trick is that the "central" set must be the same

Comment: @Numb3rs Exactly. To calculate $f\circ g$, you need $f$ to accept whatever $g$ is spitting out :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have the function domain and ranges backward: since $f\circ g$ means apply $g$ **first**, then $f$, this means $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.

When you compose, you replace the argument of the function with whatever's inside. So you have the definition of $f\circ g$ correct.

For $g\circ f$, just do the same thing:
$$g(f(x,y))=g(x^2+y^2)=\left(2(x^2+y^2),(x^2+y^2)^2\right)$$
and now you have a function that takes $(x,y)$ and gives you a 2-vector back.